# Do not display records if boolean is 1

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to select records from a mysql database where the full column 0 not 1. While running the statement, it pulls all records regardless of value.

I have the full column set to tinyint(1) and will either have a 1 or 0 to specify yes or no. But I need to display what trade_name has but not display it if it is 1.

PHP

```
$tc = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT trade_name FROM `trade_circles` WHERE full IS NULL");

while($row = $tc->fetch_assoc()) {

echo '<option value="' . $row['trade_name'] . '">' . $row['trade_name'] . '</option>';

}
```

Comment: 0 and NULL are not the same thing `where full=0` is what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0 and NULL are not the same thing `where full=0` is what you want

Comment: Thank you. Not sure why I didnt think through that :P

Comment: no worries its a common mistake for non programmer types :-) Don't for get the green tick

Answer (score 0):

So from what I understand you are trying to output a row only if full is 1 and trade_name is 0 correct? If so try the following.

```
$tc = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT trade_name FROM `trade_circles` WHERE full = 1 AND trade_name = 0");

while($row = $tc->fetch_assoc()) {

echo '<option value="' . $row['trade_name'] . '">' . $row['trade_name'] . '</option>';

}
```